# Can CI/CD actions be triggered by Bitbucket PR comments?

Tags: continuous-integration, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to implement slash commands which trigger CI/CD actions based upon PR comments in Bitbucket. In GitHub, there's a `issue_comment` event which catches these and enabled CI/CD flows from the comment. However, I don't see anything similar from Bitbucket.

Is this possible?
If not, is there some other way to meet the requirement of triggering actions based upon PR comments?

Answer (score 1):

As of today, this is not directly supported.
One way to do this, create a webhook in Bitbucket which triggers your custom code on the event 'Comment created'(https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/event-payloads/#EventPayloads-Commentcreated.1).
Your custom code will read the comment and based on a regex match you can decide whether or not to trigger a pipeline.

Comment: The webhook would presumably require software/listener running on external infrastructure, yes? For my use case, I need to avoid that added surface area. Perhaps can my CI/CD pipeline conditionally post a message back to the PR, with a deep link to a suggested manual pipeline which takes further action?